# .NET MAUI SQL Server doesn't work in release mode

Tags: c#, sql-server, maui

I am using .NET MAUI. I connect to SQL Server using an IP address. I have a specific scenario that requires me to connect to SQL Server within my .NET MAUI application. It works fine in debug mode, and I can connect to SQL Server. However, I am unable to connect to it in release mode.

**Error**

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

**Connection String**

Server=Server,1434;Database=DB;User ID=penn;Password=asdaf;Encrypt=false;TrustServerCertificate=true;

Could you please help me?

I tried to change the connection string and also searched in the MAUI github repo but no luck.

**Additional Info**

I am getting this in Event Viewer

The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/DESKTOP-TKH5FGS:1433 ] for the SQL Server service. Windows return code: 0xffffffff, state: 63. Failure to register a SPN might cause integrated authentication to use NTLM instead of Kerberos. This is an informational message. Further action is only required if Kerberos authentication is required by authentication policies and if the SPN has not been manually registered.

Comment: 1434 isn't the tcp port you're looking for. That's the Dedicated Administrator Connection and allows only a single connection from a member of the sysadmins group. The default port for the `MSSQLSERVER` instance used for Developer, Standard and Enterprise editions is tcp/1433.

Comment: Thank you. Let me verify with 1433. I utilized the RemoDB android app and successfully connected through port 1434. Trying with 1433 now

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I checked it and it isn't working.

Comment: You can [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) if it's helpful to others facing the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am not able to accept my own answer. **You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.**

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by updating the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient Package to the latest pre-release version and adding INTERNET permission to the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

MSSQLSvc/DESKTOP-TKH5FGS:1433 is very not correct, the syntax is either: COMPUTER/InstanceName or COMPUTER,Port.

There are two ways of connecting to SQL Server through the network:

- instance name, connection string looks like: 192.168.10.1/INSTANCE_NAME or COMPUTER_NAME/INSTANCE_NAME
- port, connection string server looks like: 192.168.10.1,1433 or COMPUTER_NAME,1433.

Instance name allows hiding the port details behind a constant name, but requires SQL Server Browser Service to broadcast the port data on the network.

Ports are more explicit, but then you need to figure out on which port the server is listening. It's usually 1433, but can be something else. To see the actual IP, you can go to SQL Server Configuration Manager and open the correct server:

[image: Configuration]

Comment: I use the server like this: 192.168.10.1,1433. I changed the port to 1433 from 1434 but still it isn't working. I am able to connect to SQL Server using RemoDB(An android app which can be used to connect to different databases)

Comment: But is the port actually 1433?

Comment: Yes, It is, As I can connect to it using RemoDB and also in Debug mode using .NET MAUI but not in release mode

Comment: Ok, but are your connection strings different between debug and release mode? There shouldn't be any code difference

Comment: No, There is no difference. I updated the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient to latest prelease and now get this error:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An Internal Exception was caught)